# How to verify Image in Coded Ui test?

Tags: c#, testing, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am new to coded UI test, Here my Problem is i want to validate Image, Is it possible to validate Images in coded UI or Not ?

here i want to Validate tick mark. i attached Snapshot also.

Could any body help me out from this issue.

TIA--[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFFxz.png)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the answer is no. You need an image recognition library.

Comment: All UI controls have a `CaptureImage` method. But how you check whether the image is as wanted is up to you.